# Using Ruby, how to get the column types for a google sheet?

Tags: ruby, google-sheets

In a google sheet, different column could define different types, such as plain text, number or date. Using ruby, is there anyway to get these attributes?

Comment: Have you tried the [`google-client-api`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby)?

Comment: I am trying google-client-api, but could not find an suitable function for that

Comment: I don't have api access to google but https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_multiples_ranges might help